# How to Populate dropdownlist with JQUERY function with Value and Text Both?

Tags: jquery

Hi I am writing a function in Jquery
In which I have 2 Values

ID and Name

ID -1 
name- ABC.

ID - 2 
name - BCD.

how to Populate so that we can get both name and ID in the DropdownList.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$("#SelectTeam2").bind("change",function() {
    var TeamID1 = $("#SelectTeam1").val(); 
    var TeamID2 = $("#SelectTeam2").val();
    var Team1 = $("#SelectTeam1 option:selected").text();
    var Team2 = $("#SelectTeam2 option:selected").text();
});
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I am fetching the variable from web service. and i am getting two records along with ID and Name. Just looking for set it to dropdown list.

Comment: @Akash, this doesn't answer Rory's question. How does your code look like?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, My code look like this.. $("#SelectTeam2").bind("change",function(){
            
            var TeamID1 = $("#SelectTeam1").val();
            var TeamID2 =  $("#SelectTeam2").val();
            
            var Team1 = $("#SelectTeam1 option:selected").text();
            var Team2 = $("#SelectTeam2 option:selected").text();
           this are two variables of mine. and i want to set this two items in dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var array = [{name:Team1, value:TeamID1},{name:Team2, value:TeamID2}];
                 alert(array);

```
            $.each(array, function(index, item) {
            $("#SelectTossWon").get(0).options[$("#SelectTossWon").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.name, item.value);
            alert(item.name);
            alert(item.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$.fn.AddItem = function(ID, Name) {
    $(this).append($('<option></option>').val(ID).html(Name));
});

$("#selectID").AddItem(1, "ABC");
$("#selectID").AddItem(2, "BCD");
```

Comment: It means this function must be applied to a jQuery object, which the function expects to be containing a `select` element.